# How can we hide/remove country & state from Estimate Shipping and Tax form in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.0.2

I want functionality to calculate shipping estimation only from the zip code. I don't want to show country & state fields in shipping estimation form.

Is anyone know how can we achieve this functionality in magento2 on cart page like attached screenshot?[image]

Comment: To disable the state, you have to go on *Stores -> Seetings -> General -> state options*
and unselect your country from there. In *"allow to choose state"* you set *"no"* to make the country disappear. I'm working on it too... but no answers yet.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a very old question, however adding the method we chose so that it can help someone in future.

**Note:**  This option will be useful if you have only one country where you ship to and State is not mandatory.

We tried to achieve this programmatically, but it was breaking functionality, also, unnecessary file changes were required. Also without country the zip code will not work, as zip code can be same across the countries, so we wrote CSS to hide the Country and State options.

Sample code below,

```
.checkout-cart-index div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"],
.checkout-cart-index div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] {
      display: none !important;
}
```

Since the ID of the country and state fields change dynamically, we referred to them from name of the div.

This is not an optimized solution, but a quick and safe one as it will not impact any functionality.

Comment: I need help i have facing issue

Comment: did you tried this solution? what issue are you facing

Comment: actually i need help this question please check it https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248882/magento-admin-panel-getting-asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error-after-remove-a

Comment: added answer there.

Comment: @DeepikaJaniyani, this is not working for me,

Comment: @jafarpinjar are you using default magento 2 theme?

Comment: @DeepikaJaniyani, No I have created new theme with parent as Luma

Comment: @jafarpinjar is there any demo url to see

Comment: @DeepikaJaniyani, No i am working on localhost. can we not hide with xml, ?css will be problem because on page load the content won't be there to apply display none

Comment: Estimate form occurs only after the page load, with ajax response, so display none is not a proper solution i guess

Comment: Problem with XML was that the validations that are added for Country and State fields don't get removed easily. I had tried that initially.