# Magento admin panel getting Asymmetric transaction rollback error after remove all product

Tags: magento2, admin, error

When editing  a product and trying to save it, I get the following error message:

```
Asymmetric transaction rollback error
```

This error comes after remove all product in admin side so it's scary error comes.  Has anyone else encountered this? Please share the fix :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Reindex by using the following command

   ```
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```
2. Run below commands

   ```
   rm -rf var/cache/*
   rm -rf var/page_cache/*
   rm -rf var/generation/*
   ```
3. Give permissions to var/generation folder.

You can read more about this in https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error/

[New Product: "Asymmetric transaction rollback." error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/new-product-asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error)

Comment: actually my issue comes randomly after this error all product remove in admin side

Comment: try indexing once, it should help. are the products present in DB?

Comment: this answer not proper solution because if any one product edit attribute after this error comes but not every time it's comes consistently

Comment: all product remove in admin side when this error comes i have check it catloag ->product inside (o) record display

Comment: I have to getting this error in my exception.log if you have idea reply me ---->main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Asymmetric transaction rollback.' in /home/XXXX/public_html/XXX/XXXX/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:

Comment: I need help please go thorough this question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251650/magento2-category-custom-textarea-with-wysiwyg-editor-attribute-value-blank-iss"

Comment: If you have any idea please share it because i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

**What does asymmetric means?**

If  you goolge this keywords, you will only find articles about Magento 2. It seems as it some Magento developer created this error message. The error message comes directly from Magento 2 database pdo mysql layer in `/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` line 278

> throw new \Exception(AdapterInterface::ERROR_ASYMMETRIC_ROLLBACK_MESSAGE);

If a rollback should be done and transactionLevel is not set correctly this error is displayed. So you may contact your mysql database host to configure your database for Magento 2.

**Conclusion**

Asymmetric transaction rollback errors are strange, they have something to do with MySQL settings. The error sometimes appears and I was not able to reproduce it. Reindexing and cache clearing can solve this issue.

So ideally `reindexing` and `cache flush` is solution for it.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I agree your solution but this error comes after remove all product in my admin side so i can't figure out why this is happened.

Comment: So now you are not able to add new product?

Comment: I can  import product it's coming in admin side but my issue this error comes all product remove it.

Comment: It means you are not able to edit product.

Comment: Try to change reindexing mode by following this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110976/new-product-asymmetric-transaction-rollback-error

Comment: I have to edit the product and save it

Comment: I try it but my error  is comes randomly when my admin side here product 18k after this error comes remove all product so all data lost .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85235/discussion-between-saniya-and-chirag-patel).