# How to hide country and state & state from cart page?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

As I am new in Magento and  I stuck with a problem for 4 days. I want to hide the country selection dropdown and state from cart page as My requirements to provide shipping only single country. How can I achieve this?

I already tried this solution but it does not work for me

[solutions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122395/how-can-we-hide-remove-country-state-from-estimate-shipping-and-tax-form-in-ma)

Thanks in advanced

Comment: You want to show only one country on the checkout page right?

Answer (score 0):

**Select Country Which you want to Display on the checkout page :-**

```
Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Country Options > Allow Countries
```